# How to pull snapshot key & values into list through Map<>?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I've been following the official Firebase tutorial for using a real-time database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXBJZD0fBa4

I am able to pull all the data from the firebase real-time database. However, the method below to do so, provides a list of the data, with no reference to the parent keys (snapshot.key). An ideal scenario would be to have a key property within the Item class (item.key), so I can call upon it directly from the list.

```
class DatabaseModel {

  final itemsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('/Contents');

  Stream<List<Items>> getItemssStream() {

    final itemsStream = itemsRef.onValue;

    final streamToPublish = itemsStream.map((event) {

      final itemsMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>);

      final itemsList = itemsMap.entries.map((element) {
        return Items.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(element.value));
      }).toList();

      return itemsList;    

    });

    return streamToPublish;
  }
  
}
```

```
class Items{
  final String item;
  final String expiryDate;
  final String quantity;
  final String user;

  Items({required this.item, required this.expiryDate, required this.quantity, required this.user});

  //Mapping from real-time database
  factory Items.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Items(
      item: data['item'],
      expiryDate: data['exp'],
      quantity: data['qty'],
      user: data['user'],
    );
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code you only use the `element.value` of each node in your results:

```
return Items.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(element.value));
```

If you also want to get the key of each item, you will have to also use `element.key` in there and pass that to your `Items` object.

---

Something like this:

```
Items.fromRTDB(element.key, Map<String, dynamic>.from(element.value));

...

class Items{
  final String key;
  final String item;
  final String expiryDate;
  final String quantity;
  final String user;

  Items({required this.key, required this.item, required this.expiryDate, required this.quantity, required this.user});

  //Mapping from real-time database
  factory Items.fromRTDB(String key, Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return Items(
      key: key,
      item: data['item'],
      expiryDate: data['exp'],
      quantity: data['qty'],
      user: data['user'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated Frank! For future readers, this was the working implementation: `return Items.fromRTDB((element.key), Map<String, dynamic>.from(element.value));`

Comment: Oops, good catch on the `element.key` being in the wrong spot in the call site.     I fixed it in the answer too. If such a mistake happens in the future again, you can click the edit link to fix it yourself. Most answerers appreciate such fixes, since they are pure improvements.