# Firebase data Cannot be retrieved to Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a Realtime database in Firebase to Flutter. The data should be parsed to be used in the building of a listview inside a future builder. However, after I execute the code I got an error that displayed on the Emulator screen. My understanding is that there is a type mismatch inside the code of `firebaseCalls` method. Below is my code `Main.dart`, data model, Firebase data, and Error Message. Any help to figure out the issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Main.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'datamodel.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  Future<List<Menu>> firebaseCalls(DatabaseReference ref) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await ref.child('Task').get();
     String? jsondata =dataSnapshot.value as String?; // just in case String is not working
    //String jsondata = dataSnapshot.children;//   value;//[0]['Task'];// should be dataSnapshot.value
    // Decode Json as a list
    final list = json.decode(jsondata!);// as List<dynamic>;
    return list.map((e) => Menu.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            //drawer: _drawer(data),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('الصف السادس العلمي'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
                future: firebaseCalls(ref), // async work
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.none:
                      return new Text('Press button to start');
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return new Text('Loading....');
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError)
                        return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      else
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                              _buildTiles(snapshot.data[index]),
                        );
                  }
                } // builder
                )
        )
    );
  }

  ////////////////////////////////////////////
  Widget _buildTiles(Menu list) {
    if (list.subMenu?.length == 0)
      return new ListTile(
        leading: Icon(list.icon),
        title: Text(
          list.name!,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: list.font?.toDouble(), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onTap: () => debugPrint("I was clicked"),
      );
    return new ExpansionTile(
      leading: Icon(list.icon),
      title: Text(
        list.name!,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: list.font?.toDouble(), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      children: list.subMenu!.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }//_buildTiles
}
```

**datamodel.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Menu {
  String? name; // I added ?
  IconData? icon;// I added ?
  int? font;// I added ?

  List<Menu>? subMenu= [];// I added ?

  Menu({this.name, this.subMenu, this.icon,this.font});
  Menu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    font = json['font'];
    icon = json['icon'];
    if (json['subMenu'] != null) {
      //subMenu?.clear(); // I added ? it also recomand using !
      json['subMenu'].forEach((v) {
        //subMenu?.add(new Menu.fromJson(v));
        subMenu?.add(Menu.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Database:

[image: Realtime Firebase]

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await ref.child('Task').get();
String? jsondata =dataSnapshot.value as String?;
```

If we look at the screenshot of the database you shared, it's clear that the value under the `/Task` path is **not** a string. It is in fact an entire object structure, which means you get back a `Map<String, Object>` from `dataSnapshot.value`. And since that's not a `String`, you get the error that you get.

---

The proper way to get the value of the entire `Task` node is with something like:

```
Map values = dataSnapshot.value;
```

And then you can get for example the `name` with:

```
print(values["name"]);
```

---

Alternatively you get get the child snapshot, and only then get the string value from it, with something like:

```
String? name = dataSnapshot.child("name")?.value as String?;
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank. However, I tried to change it but another error appear for me I chanjged it. The new code is ```final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  Future<List<Menu>> firebaseCalls(DatabaseReference ref) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = await ref.child('Task').get();  // line 1
    Map<String, Object> jsondata = dataSnapshot.value; // Line 2
    List<dynamic> list = json.decode(jsondata!);// as List<dynamic>; // Line 3
    return list.map((e) => Menu.fromJson(e)).toList();// Line 4
  }```

Comment: the error is `error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, Object>'. (invalid_assignment at [flutter_multilevel_list_from_json] lib\main.dart:26)` for line 2 and `error: The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [flutter_multilevel_list_from_json] lib\main.dart:27)` for line 3

Comment: My goal is to get a snapshot of all The 'Task' data, then parse it into JSON file then convert JSON to a list and return it. This should be an easy task since it is common in many projects related to Realtime Firebase data. However, it seems I don't know where is the error exactly.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467457/how-to-get-value-from-map-in-firebase-database-flutter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71027043/how-to-pull-snapshot-key-values-into-list-through-map and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856697/read-list-of-items-from-firebase-database-flutter

Comment: Thank you @Frank your answers help me to reduce the search space and focus exactly on the problem. I updated my code but issues still appear. The problem is that the JSON I am working with is Iterative.  As you can see the TASK has multiple entries each has three entries font, name, and submenu. the submenu also has font,  name, and submenus. it continues for unlimited iteration. I'll update my question soon to mention the exact problem.

Comment: We can't help you with a moving target in a single question. I answered why you got the original error you posted and how to get rid of that. If you're having trouble after that, I recommend posting a new question, but please spend time creating a separate, isolated [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.

Comment: Sure!  I'll  make the minimal repo. Thanks again for your time @Frank.

Comment: the question is this     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833929/parsing-iterative-json-from-firebase-to-flutter